# How to bypass android dialog outside click

Tags: android, dialog

What I want to do is to show the dialog message but make it still possible to click on the items behind. On any click, the dialog would dismiss

Right now I need to click once to dismiss the dialog and a second time to click on a field.

It is something possible ? Or is there an alternative to using Dialogs?

Edit: Solution found by adding Layout Flags to the window. 
In kotlin:

> dialog.window?.setLayout(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)

Comment: u can use mohankumar answer

Comment: If you just dont want to close the dialog onclicking the outside use `dialog.setcancelable(false)` . or if you want to still  use your Views behind the dialog refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

By using Dialog you cannot achieve what you are looking for. instead of using Dialog **USE FRAGMENT**.

The examples are given in official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Answer (score 0):

You Can define a full layout in the background of the dialog and set onClick listener to that layout